# C++ - Weird. Polymorphism works in one case, but doesn't work in another case

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // get the pointer from hWnd's userdata.
    La_Window* win = (La_Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // A pointer to La_Window is passed as the last parameter of CreateWindow()
        // We can get that pointer by the following line:
        La_Window* win2 = (La_Window*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams;

        // set win2 as the hWnd's userdata.
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)win2);
 
        // Any call to virtual functions of La_Window doesn't trigger polymorphism here.
        // IsMainWindow() always returns 0, which is the default implementation.
        std::cout << win2->IsMainWindow() << std::endl;
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        // But polymorphism works here!
        // IsMainWindow() returns 1, which is the child class' implementation.
        std::cout << win->IsMainWindow() << std::endl;
        ...

    }
    ...
}
```

Polymorphism doesn't work in `case WM_CREATE`. However, it works in `case WM_DESTROY`!
I have printed `win` and `win2`. They have exactly the same value. The `this` pointer is passed to `CreateWindow()` in the constructor of `La_Window` instead of its child class. I have tried to pass the `this` pointer of its child class to `La_Window()` and then pass it to `CreateWindow()`. But it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: CreateWindow passes WM_CREATE immediately to window procedure. When window proc is executed, you use `this` pointer of class object to access virtual functions in constructor, which is illegal in C++. Avoid calling virtual function of object in its constructor !

Comment: That is the reason why in MFC windows are created in two steps: first the C++ object is created, and only when it is fully constructed a method is used to create the Windows API window attached to the C++ object. You should try to do the same...

Comment: For more info why virtual mechanism is disabled in ctors, you could read [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors)